# Difficulty using Itertools cycle

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, turtle-graphics

At the moment I have defined many shapes in `Turtle` using `begin_poly` and `end_poly` then `register_shape`. I want to be able to put all of these values into a list and, with a press of a button, cycle through the list hence changing the `Turtle` shape. I am having difficulty achieving this with `Itertools` and was wondering for some assistance on how I could achieve this.

Edit: I got it working in the end, I appended all the values into a list then used a counter to choose which index to go to.

Comment: Explain how it "doesn't work". http://sscce.org/

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you don't actually do anything with the values obtained from the generator.

Comment: I edited the question. When I tried this, it goes to a shape but when I press h again, it won't move off of it. It ghosts to other shapes so I know that it is cycling but it isn't setting to a new shape.

Comment: Can you simplify your entire code to something you can post?  I think you have more problems than using a generator.

Comment: Here is the code for the shapes. I did from turtle import *.

Comment: This is, if anything, even less comprehensible now. Your code isn't even indented correctly. I am voting to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 34):

First, create the generator:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> shape_list = ["square", "triangle", "circle", "pentagon", "star", "octagon"]
>>> g = itertools.cycle(shape_list)
```

Then call `next()` whenever you want another one.

```
>>> next(g)
'square'
>>> next(g)
'triangle'
>>> next(g)
'circle'
>>> next(g)
'pentagon'
>>> next(g)
'star'
>>> next(g)
'octagon'
>>> next(g)
'square'
>>> next(g)
'triangle'
```

Here's a simple program:

```
import itertools
shape_list = ["square", "triangle", "circle", "pentagon", "star", "octagon"]
g = itertools.cycle(shape_list)
for i in xrange(8):
    shape = next(g)
    print "Drawing",shape
```

Output:

```
Drawing square
Drawing triangle
Drawing circle
Drawing pentagon
Drawing star
Drawing octagon
Drawing square
Drawing triangle
```

Comment: I tried what I did in the edited question but it still isn't working. :S

Comment: -1 how does this take OP beyond what they have in the question?

Comment: @Marcin: Most of the code in the question is *from* this answer.  Originally it seemed like the OP was constructing a new `cycle` instance every time, although it's hard to tell from `next (itertools.cycle (shape_list)) 1 next (itertools.cycle (shape_list)) 2`, whatever that might mean.  This answer separated out the generator creation from the getting of the next element, which was a perfectly plausible reading of the OP's problem.

Comment: Unfortunately Mark the code still doesn't work. :( Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Marcin, the OP has edited his question.  As DSM says the original question wasn't clear.

Comment: `g.next()` doesn't work in Python 3: _AttributeError: 'itertools.cycle' object has no attribute 'next'_

You need to call `next(g)`